# Can I use serial port and RFID reader on Arduino Pro Mini?

Tags: arduino, serial, atmega, bluetooth, rfid

I have Arduino Pro Mini, HC-06 bluetooth module, and Mifare RC522 RFID reader. Bluetooth module connects to serial port, and RFID connects to SDA, SCK, MOSI, MISO, ground, reset, and 3.3V pins. I want to know if there might be a conflict between RFID reader and ATmega serial port. The reader will be used for reading and wiring cards. Bluetooth is there for monitoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ATmega168 has separate pins for I<sup>2</sup>C (PC4:5), SPI (PB2:5), and UART (PD0:1). There will be no conflict between the devices provided you use the MFRC522 via either SPI or I<sup>2</sup>C. Note that the Arduino Pro Mini is programmed via its UART, so you may need to disconnect the HC-06 when programming via the serial port.